# Angularjs how to add/remove dynamically input form with ng-Repeat on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to add dynamically some input forms with Angularjs on Google Maps. When i am adding the new item, it just erases the old one and make a new box on it.

How can i create one under the input box? and also remove it dynamically when they are too many?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzcjyfxk/1/) version.

**html**

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="item in items"><input id="fieldsme" type="text" placeholder="Type new location" ng-model="item.direction"> 
</div> <button id="buttononmap" ng-click="add()">New box</button> 
<div id="routes3-map"></div> </div>
```

**js**

```
function MapCtrl($scope) {
var myLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(50.2381736,9.9646571);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 8,
  center: myLocation,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.BIG,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
  }
};
$scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('routes3-map'), mapOptions);

$scope.items = [direction=""];

$scope.add = function () {
  $scope.items.push({
    direction: ""
  });
};
```

}

**css**

```
#routes3-map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}


#fieldsme {
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#buttononmap {
  margin-left: 210px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: might consider using a google map directive that already exists instead of reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Items are added to the array but not in the same form of your initial one. So change the creation of the array:

```
$scope.items = [{direction:""}];
```

Also, because of the `ng-repeat`, you create multiple items with the same id, and more importantly, with the same css style so they are all being placed at the same spot.

If you want to use `position: absolute`, you can use `ng-style` to place them based on their position in the array:

```
// init top variable with the calculation of the wanted margin-top
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-init="top = (50 + ($index * 20)) + 'px'">
    <input  ng-style="{'margin-top': top}" class="fieldsme" type="text" placeholder="Type new location" ng-model="item.direction"/>
</div>
```

For removing items, just set up a button which calls a function with it's row index:

```
<button ng-style="{'margin-top': top}" class="fieldsme"  ng-click="remove($index)">X</button>
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.remove = function (index) {
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Also, change the `ng-repeat` to be by `$index` so it will update the `margin-top` as well.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-init="top = (50 + ($index * 20)) + 'px'">
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/35h5z1bp/).

Comment: ng-init did the trick! thanks! and how can i remove the input field with another button near the newly created input field?

Comment: how can i move the X(remove) button to the end of the input field? i have tried with text-align but no change.

Comment: you can just give it a bigger margin-left